# Error while installing OpenALPR on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, openalpr, make-install

I have just started using Raspberry PI 3. I'm trying to install an open source library named as OpenALPR on it. It's a library that takes an image of a vehicle's license plate as an argument and returns the text written on it. I've been following this link to install the library.

https://blog.vinczejanos.info/2017/05/01/install-openalpr-on-raspberry-pi-3-part-2/

I'm on the `install OpenALPR` step specified in the above link. I've encountered the following error on the last build command of that step i.e. `make install`

```
[ 21%] Built target support
[ 23%] Built target video
[ 51%] Built target openalpr
[ 52%] Built target alpr
[ 55%] Built target alprd
[ 56%] Built target openalpr-utils-prepcharsfortraining
[ 59%] Built target openalpr-utils-benchmark
[ 60%] Built target openalpr-utils-binarizefontsheet
[ 61%] Built target openalpr-utils-classifychars
[ 63%] Built target openalpr-utils-calibrate
[ 64%] Built target openalpr-utils-tagplates
[ 66%] Built target openalpr-utils-sortstate
[ 69%] Built target unittests
[ 96%] Built target openalpr-static
[ 97%] Built target simpleini
[ 99%] Built target openalprpy
[100%] Built target openalprgo
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebugInfo"
-- Installing: /usr/bin/alpr
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:50 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file "/usr/src/openalpr/src/build/alpr" to
  "/usr/bin/alpr".


Makefile:126: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I can assure that all the steps above this one have been completed successfully. Please guide me regarding this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error has been resolved. All I did was executed the command `make install` without `sudo` which didn't give permission to copy files. Once I executed it as `sudo make install` it executed perfectly and is working now.